# Should accept only numbers not special characters for account number in ionic mobile view

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, eclipse-plugin

In mobile view,I am unable to accepting only numbers not special characters in mobile view, following is my code:

`<ion-item>
 <ion-label >Account Number *</ion-label>
 <ion-input type="number" [pattern]="[0-9]*" name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" digit></ion-input>`

Comment: type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*"
try this

Comment: ok.!thks i will check! but i tried with type="tel" inputmode="numeric" it is not working

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10161

Comment: Refer this `text-mask` link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask

Comment: thanks Saurabh !!actually i am using IONIC 2 .so,i will try !